# How to propertly Implement DefaultModelBinder when incoming data is different than action argument

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a custom model binder that converts the request, which could be deserialized to an `IEnumerable<GenericModel>`, into the action argument `IEnumerable<IDataItem>`. I'm having trouble figuring out which method to override from the `DefaultModelBinder`, how to implement it, and what exactly it should return.

Spending the last few days combing through the googles and finding a ton of info, I still don't have a good understanding of the clear purpose of the virtual methods BindModel vs. CreateModel vs. OnModelUpdated vs. etc.

---

The request is a json array of `GenericModel`s that needs to be converted to an `IEnumerable<IDataItem>` for this action...

```
public ActionResult Save(IEnumerable<IDataItem> models)
```

My model binder (which inherits from `DefaultModelBinder`) was implementing `CreateModel` and tried to manually set `bindingContext.ModelType` from `IDataItem` to `GenericModel` so that I could properly get the `PropertyDescriptor` for each property, get its value, and set the properties for the `GenericModel` instance. Once I had a hydrated `GenericModel` I would create the correct concrete `IDataItem` and return it back to the `DefaultModelBinder` to continue it's binding and validation (which I need since some properties of the `IDataItem` are decorated with `ValidationAttributes`).

The problem is I could never quite figure out how to properly iterate through the `GenericModel` properties and set it's values from the `ValueProvider`.

My thought was that I could change the `bindingContext.ModelType` from `IDataItem` to `GenericModel` and iterate through it's `PropertyDescriptors`, but `bindingContext.ModelType` doesn't have a setter and although it seems to derive from `bindingContext.ModelMetadata.Model`, changing that has no effect - `bindingContext.ModelType` remains `IDataItem`.

```
public class DataItemModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder {
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) {
        GenericModel model = CreateGenericModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);         
        // just return a dummy instance of IDataItem so I can debug 
        return new TextboxModel();
    }

    private GenericModel CreateGenericModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        GenericModel model = new GenericModel();
        // I was thinking this would change bindingContext.ModelType but it doesn't
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata.Model = model;

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in GetFilteredModelProperties(controllerContext, bindingContext)) {
            string prefix = CreateSubPropertyPrefix(bindingContext.ModelName, descriptor.Name);
            ModelBindingContext context = new ModelBindingContext {
                ModelMetadata = bindingContext.PropertyMetadata[descriptor.Name],
                ModelName = prefix,
                ModelState = bindingContext.ModelState,
                ValueProvider = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            };
            IModelBinder propertyBinder = Binders.GetBinder(descriptor.PropertyType);
            object value = GetPropertyValue(controllerContext, context, descriptor, propertyBinder);

            // Great, I've set the descriptor, but how do I set the actual model property?
            descriptor.SetValue(context.Model, value);
        }
        return model;
    }
}
```

Am I overriding the proper method? What's the proper way to implement a solution for my given problem?

Hopefully my circumstances and problem are clear. If I can elaborate further to answer any questions I will :)

Comment: Have no idea, but [There is even a request for implementing sample custom binder on mvc github](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/1963)

Comment: custom model binders are a pain. im confused though as to why you need one at all though. if you have a List<GenericModel> and GenericModel : IDataItem surely it should just work?

Comment: `GenericModel` does not inherit from `IDataItem` and for purposes of securitiy and rendering it can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I wasn't too far off.

In order to iterate through an objects `PropertyDescriptor`s you need to create a new `ModelBindingContext` from the existing binding context passed into the method you've overridden. Here's a snippet, you can find the complete answer below.

```
GenericModel model = new ModelBindingContext {
    ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, typeof(GenericModel)),
    ValueProvider = bindingContext.ValueProvider,
    ModelName = bindingContext.ModelName
};
```

As you iterate through the properties you create a new `ModelBindingContext` for each property you're iterating, get the `IModelBinder`, get the property value and finally set the property value, which hydrates the `GenericModel` you created the original `ModelBindingContext` for.

```
public class DataItemModelBinder: DefaultModelBinder {

    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType) {
        GenericModel model = CreateGenricModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        //this is basically a factory that creates the correct IDataItem 
        // given the newly hydrated GenericModel. It doesn't really apply
        // for the given question/answer so I left it out.
        return CreateDataItem(model);
    }

    private IDataItem CreateDataItem(GenericModel genericModel) {
        IModelRetriever retriever = GetRetreiver(genericModel.DataType);
        return retriever.GetModel(genericModel);
    }

    private GenericModel CreateGenricModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        GenericModel model = new GenericModel();
        ModelBindingContext context = CreateGenericFieldBindingContext(bindingContext, model);

        foreach (PropertyDescriptor descriptor in GetFilteredModelProperties(controllerContext, context)) {
            string prefix = CreateSubPropertyPrefix(context.ModelName, descriptor.Name);
            ModelBindingContext propertyContext = new ModelBindingContext {
                ModelMetadata = context.PropertyMetadata[descriptor.Name],
                ModelName = prefix,
                ValueProvider = context.ValueProvider
            };
            IModelBinder propertyBinder = Binders.GetBinder(descriptor.PropertyType);
            object value = GetPropertyValue(controllerContext, propertyContext, descriptor, propertyBinder);

            SetProperty(controllerContext, context, descriptor, value);
        }
        return model;
    }

    private ModelBindingContext CreateGenericFieldBindingContext(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, GenericModel model) {
        return new ModelBindingContext {
            ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => model, typeof(GenericModel)),
            ValueProvider = bindingContext.ValueProvider,
            ModelName = bindingContext.ModelName
        };
    }

    private string CreateSubPropertyPrefix(string prefix, string propertyName) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix))
            return propertyName;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
            return prefix;

        return (prefix + "." + propertyName);
    }   
}
```